# Display many2one field in OpenERP view

Tags: view, odoo

There's a field of line_ids in the class of 'purchase.requisition' :

```
  'line_ids' : fields.one2many('purchase.requisition.line','requisition_id',
               'Products to Purchase',states={'done': [('readonly', True)]}),
```

And I add a many2one field to 'purchase.order.line' :

```
 'requisition_line_id': fields.many2one('purchase.requisition.line' ,
                 u'Requisition Line',readonly = True ,  ondelete = 'restrict' ),
```

Now , how can I display then name field of 'purchase.requisition' in the view of 'purchase.order.line' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you fields.related.

Example :

```
class hr_employee(osv.osv):
    _name = "hr.employee"

    _columns = {
        'address_id': fields.many2one('res.partner.address', 'Working Address'),
        'city': fields.related('address_id', 'city', type='char', string='City'),
    }
```

Then after add moduel_view.xml at appropriate place.

```
<field name="city" />
```

Here you see an example of fields.related.

Now similar try to fix your problem.

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks ! It works well .
Is there any method to fix the problem without adding field .

Comment: Yes, you can use name_get method or other functional fields.

BUT,  fields.related is best and right fix for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Goto [View Inheritance](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/view_inheritence.html) It will help you a lot.